# Fancy Header Custom Counter References

Tags: pdftex, fancyhdr, counters, variable, setcounter

I'm trying to typeset a bible. In the header should be the current book name then the current chapter and current verse. By "current" I mean the next one in that page (or even the most recent one before that page; I haven't decided which way it should be). For instance, if the first chapter and verse of a page is 2:15, the header should say "<book> 2:15".

Obviously I'm doing some horribly wrong, but the output is so terribly erratic that I don't even know where to start. Here is an example:

```tex
\nonstopmode
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1.1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}\newcounter{verse}
\def\book{}
\fancyhead[c]{\book \arabic{chapter}:\arabic{verse}}
\fancyfoot{}
\begin{document}
\def\book{Genesis}
\section*{Genesis}\begin{multicols}{2}\noindent\setcounter{chapter}{1}\textbf{\huge 1} In [the] beginning...
\setcounter{verse}{2}\textsuperscript{2}and the earth...\\
\setcounter{verse}{3}\textsuperscript{3}and God says...\\
\setcounter{verse}{4}\textsuperscript{4}And God sees...\\
\pagebreak
\setcounter{verse}{5}\textsuperscript{5}and God calls...\\
\setcounter{chapter}{2}\vspace{.2cm}\\\textbf{\huge 2} \setcounter{verse}{1}And the heavens...\\
\setcounter{verse}{2}\textsuperscript{2}and God completes...\\
\setcounter{chapter}{3}\vspace{.2cm}\\\textbf{\huge 3} And the serpent...\\
\pagebreak
\setcounter{verse}{2}\textsuperscript{2}And the woman...\\
\setcounter{verse}{3}\textsuperscript{3}but from the...\\
\setcounter{verse}{4}\textsuperscript{4}And the serpent...\\
\setcounter{verse}{22}\textsuperscript{22}And Zillah, she also bears Tubal-Cain, an instructor of every craftsman in bronze and iron; and a sister of Tubal-Cain [is] Naamah. 
\setcounter{verse}{23}\textsuperscript{23}And Lamech says to his wives: “Adah and Zillah, hear my voice; Wives of Lamech, give ear [to] my saying: For I have slain a man for my wound,
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I'm reusing the `chapter` counter and creating a new counter, `verse`, and `\def\book{Genesis}`. When I run this through `pdflatex`, I expect the first page's header to be, perhaps "Genesis 1:1". Instead, it's "Genesis3:4". I could imagine the heading being "0:0" (because the book, chapter, and verse may not have been initialized by the time the header is rendered), but it's referring to the last verse of the book. This suggests that the fancyhdr package only gets the references at the very end of typesetting then copies them in to every page?? In the larger context with the whole book of Genesis, the results are even more perplexing, but I'll save you the gory details.

How do I get fancyhdr to render the "current" values of these variables in the header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this with the marks mechanism. The easiest is if you make a macro for starting a verse (this also is less typing) and set the mark in that macro.

Here is a start.

**EDIT: Cleanup the macros.** I have put the `\vspace` in `\startchapter`, put some `\par` and `\noindents` in the beginning of the chapters and the verses (you could set `\parindent` to `0pt` instead). Also filled up one page to show the effect of the next chapter beginning at the top of the page.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1.1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}\newcounter{verse}
\def\book{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[c]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\newcommand{\startchapter}[1]{%
  \setcounter{chapter}{#1}%
  \vspace{.2cm}\par\noindent\textbf{\huge #1}%
  \markright{\book\ \thechapter:1}%
}
\newcommand{\Verse}[1]{%
  \noindent\textsuperscript{#1}%
  \markright{\book\ \thechapter:#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\def\book{Genesis}
\section*{Genesis}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\startchapter{1}
In [the] beginning...
\Verse{2}and the earth...\\
\Verse{3}and God says...\\[22cm]
\Verse{4}And God sees...\\[22cm]
\Verse{5}and God calls...\\[22cm]
\startchapter{2}
And the heavens...\\
\Verse{2}and God completes...\\
\startchapter{3}
And the serpent...\\
\newpage
\Verse{2}And the woman...\\
\Verse{3}but from the...\\
\Verse{4}And the serpent...\\
\Verse{22}And Zillah, she also bears Tubal-Cain, an instructor of every craftsman in bronze and iron; and a sister of Tubal-Cain [is] Naamah. 
\Verse{23}And Lamech says to his wives: “Adah and Zillah, hear my voice; Wives of Lamech, give ear [to] my saying: For I have slain a man for my wound,
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This was the original picture with Genesis 1:5 at the top of the page.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly right, thank you. May I press just a bit further? On a page that starts a chapter, the header now shows the most recent verse (and it makes sense); is there any way to show the NEXT verse? For instance, a page that starts with chapter 3 verse 1 should say "<book> 3:1" rather than "<book> 2:5" (the last verse from the previous page)?

Comment: Actually, that is how it already works. You may have been misled by the Genesis 1:5 in the picture, but that is because that verse is on the top of the page. I have edited the code to show that it works.